# css nested tree hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I am having a very simple nested tree list and i want on hover of .myLinks change the background of just the hovered item. How can i achieve that?

```css
.myLinks{
    
    min-height:10px;
    min-width:10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.myLinks:hover{
        background: red;  
    }
```

```html
<div class="myLinks">
  Some Links
  <div class="myLinks">
    Some Links
    <div class="myLinks">
      Some Links
      <div class="myLinks">
        Some Links
        <div class="myLinks">
          Some Links
          <div class="myLinks">Some Links</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mouseenter and mousleave event here

In the solution here I assumed that you want to highlight the links.

```js
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')];

links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    if(links.includes(link.parentNode))
      link.parentNode.classList.remove('myLinksHover');
    link.classList.add('myLinksHover');
  });
  
  link.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    if(links.includes(link.parentNode))
      link.parentNode.classList.add('myLinksHover');
    link.classList.remove('myLinksHover');
  });
});
```

```css
.myLinks{
    
    min-height:10px;
    min-width:10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.myLinksHover{
        background: red;  
    }
```

```html
<div class="myLinks">
  Some Links
  <a href="BLA">Hi</a>
  <div class="myLinks">
    Some Links
    <a href="BLA">Hi</a>
    <div class="myLinks">
      Some Links
      <a href="BLA">Hi</a>
      <div class="myLinks">
        Some Links
        <a href="BLA">Hi</a>
        <div class="myLinks">
          Some Links
          <a href="BLA">Hi</a>
          <div class="myLinks">Some Links
          <a href="BLA">Hi</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```